# Laravel Scheduler creating thousands of log files in tmp folder

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I have a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16.04 server running Laravel.

I have a couple crons running every minute in the scheduler that trigger the Quickbooks API library. Everytime it runs it logs a text file similar to below. It creates a request and response txt file:

```
 RESPONSE URI FOR SEQUENCE ID 04745
==================================
https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123456/query?minorversion=54

RESPONSE HEADERS
================
date: Tue, 15 Dec 2020 18:15:51 GMT
content-type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
content-length: 1193
connection: close
server: nginx
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000
intuit_tid: 1-5fd8fd57-123456
x-spanid: d59bb673-e981-4d61-9bdf-123456
x-amzn-trace-id: Root=1-5fd8fd57-123456
set-cookie: JSESSIONID=123456.c21-pprdc21uw2apv019661-stack-b; Domain=qbo.intuit.com; Path=/; Secure; Ht$
qbo-version: 1949.239
service-time: total=8, db=3
expires: 0
cache-control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

RESPONSE BODY
=============
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2020-12-15T10:15:51.199-08:00">
  <QueryResponse startPosition="1" maxResults="1">
    <Vendor domain="QBO" sparse="false">
      <Id>6213</Id>.....
```

I don't need these logs created. How can I stop these from being created? I am not sure if they are being created from Ubuntu, Laravel or the Quickbooks API.

The bandaid is that I have a cron to remove these files from a shell script but I am trying to stop them from being generated in the first place. Thanks

Comment: In the cron command, are you sending the output somethere? Like to `/dev/null`? If not, try to modify your cron like in this [Laraver docs example](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler): `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: This is what I have setup right now `* * * * * php /var/www/inventory/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: It looks like QuickBooks API response., You can check [here](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/sdks-and-samples-collections/net/logging) or [here](https://intuit.github.io/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK/configuration.html#logging) to find out how to disable/modify response log.

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I wish logging was off by default

Comment: If helped, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a response from QuickBooks API. You can check [here](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/sdks-and-samples-collections/net/logging) or [here](https://intuit.github.io/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK/configuration.html#logging) to find out how to disable or modify response log.